# Can't get good performance with Draw(_ rect: CGRect)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics

I have a Timer() that asks the view to refresh every x seconds:

```
func updateTimer(_ stopwatch: Stopwatch) {
    stopwatch.counter = stopwatch.counter + 0.035


    Stopwatch.circlePercentage += 0.035
    stopwatchViewOutlet.setNeedsDisplay() 
}
```

--

```
class StopwatchView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

let buttonClick = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    Stopwatch.drawStopwatchFor(view: self, gestureRecognizers: buttonClick)

    }
}
```

--

```
extension Stopwatch {

static func drawStopwatchFor(view: UIView, gestureRecognizers: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let scale: CGFloat = 0.8
    let joltButtonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 75, height: 75))
    let imageView: UIImageView!

    // -- Need to hook this to the actual timer --
    let temporaryVariableForTimeIncrement = CGFloat(circlePercentage)

    // Exterior of sphere:
    let timerRadius = min(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height) / 2 * scale
    let timerCenter = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: timerCenter, radius: timerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    path.lineWidth = 2.0

    UIColor.blue.setStroke()
    path.stroke()

    // Interior of sphere
    let startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
    let arc = CGFloat.pi * 2 * temporaryVariableForTimeIncrement / 100

    let cPath = UIBezierPath()
    cPath.move(to: timerCenter)
    cPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: timerCenter.x + timerRadius * cos(startAngle), y: timerCenter.y))
    cPath.addArc(withCenter: timerCenter, radius: timerRadius * CGFloat(0.99), startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: arc + startAngle, clockwise: true)
    cPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: timerCenter.x, y: timerCenter.y))

    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = cPath.cgPath
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)

    // Jolt button
    joltButtonView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    joltButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = 38

    joltButtonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    imageView = UIImageView(frame: joltButtonView.frame)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image

    joltButtonView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizers)


    view.addSubview(joltButtonView)
    view.addSubview(imageView)


    }
}
```

My first problem is that the subviews are getting redrawn each time. The second one is that after a couple seconds, the performance starts to deteriorate really fast.

[Too many instances of the subview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2DX1.png)

[Trying to drive the blue graphic with a Timer()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iRx8.png)

Should I try to animate the circle percentage graphic instead of redrawing it each time the timer function is called?

Comment: You are currently overriding `draw()` and calling a function in which you ***add subviews*** ... very, very bad. The `draw()` function should only be used for *drawing* code. You should read Apple's docs on this [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw) and then search for some examples / tutorials similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ideally, just update the `path` for your existing shape layer. Also, for optimal drawing, don’t use `Timer`, but use `CADisplayLink` which like timer but optimized for screen refresh rate. But it’s the adding of all those views which is going to kill your performance and consume memory like crazy.

Comment: Understood. I will look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major observation is that you should not be adding subviews in `draw`. That is intended for rendering a single frame and you shouldn't be adding/removing things from the view hierarchy inside `draw`. Because you're adding subviews roughly ever 0.035 seconds, your view hierarchy is going to explode, with adverse memory and performance impact.

You should either have a `draw` method that merely calls `stroke` on your updated `UIBezierPath` for the seconds hand. Or, alternatively, if using `CAShapeLayer`, just update its `path` (and no `draw` method is needed at all).

So, a couple of peripheral observations:

1. You are incrementing your "percentage" for every tick of your timer. But you are not guaranteed the frequency with which your timer will be called. So, instead of incrementing some "percentage", you should save the start time when you start the timer, and then upon every tick of the timer, you should recalculate the amount of time elapsed between then and now when figuring out how much time has elapsed.
2. You are using a `Timer` which is good for most purposes, but for the sake of optimal drawing, you really should use a `CADisplayLink`, which is optimally timed to allow you to do whatever you need before the next refresh of the screen.

So, here is an example of a simple clock face with a sweeping second hand:

```
open class StopWatchView: UIView {

    let faceLineWidth: CGFloat = 5                                          // LineWidth of the face
    private var startTime:  Date?         { didSet { self.updateHand() } }  // When was the stopwatch resumed
    private var oldElapsed: TimeInterval? { didSet { self.updateHand() } }  // How much time when stopwatch paused

    public var elapsed: TimeInterval {                                      // How much total time on stopwatch
        guard let startTime = startTime else { return oldElapsed ?? 0 }

        return Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime) + (oldElapsed ?? 0)
    }

    private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?                            // Display link animating second hand
    public var isRunning: Bool { return displayLink != nil }                // Is the timer running?

    private var clockCenter: CGPoint {                                      // Center of the clock face
        return CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
    }

    private var radius: CGFloat {                                           // Radius of the clock face
        return (min(bounds.width, bounds.height) - faceLineWidth) / 2
    }

    private lazy var face: CAShapeLayer = {                                 // Shape layer for clock face
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth   = self.faceLineWidth
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1215686277, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.4235294163, alpha: 1).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor   = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    private lazy var hand: CAShapeLayer = {                                 // Shape layer for second hand
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override public init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()
    }

    // add necessary shape layers to layer hierarchy

    private func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(face)
        layer.addSublayer(hand)
    }

    // if laying out subviews, make sure to resize face and update hand

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateFace()
        updateHand()
    }

    // stop display link when view disappears
    //
    // this prevents display link from keeping strong reference to view after view is removed

    override open func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        if newSuperview == nil {
            pause()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - DisplayLink routines

    /// Start display link

    open func resume() {
        // cancel any existing display link, if any

        pause()

        // start new display link

        startTime = Date()
        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleDisplayLink(_:)))
        displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)

        // save reference to it

        self.displayLink = displayLink
    }

    /// Stop display link

    open func pause() {
        displayLink?.invalidate()

        // calculate floating point number of seconds

        oldElapsed = elapsed
        startTime = nil
    }

    open func reset() {
        pause()

        oldElapsed = nil
    }

    /// Display link handler
    ///
    /// Will update path of second hand.

    @objc func handleDisplayLink(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
        updateHand()
    }

    /// Update path of clock face

    private func updateFace() {
        face.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: clockCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true).cgPath
    }

    /// Update path of second hand

    private func updateHand() {
        // convert seconds to an angle (in radians) and figure out end point of seconds hand on the basis of that

        let angle = CGFloat(elapsed / 60 * 2 * .pi - .pi / 2)
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: clockCenter.x + cos(angle) * radius * 0.9, y: clockCenter.y + sin(angle) * radius * 0.9)

        // update path of hand

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: clockCenter)
        path.addLine(to: endPoint)
        hand.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

And

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stopWatchView: StopWatchView!

    @IBAction func didTapStartStopButton () {
        if stopWatchView.isRunning {
            stopWatchView.pause()
        } else {
            stopWatchView.resume()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func didTapResetButton () {
        stopWatchView.reset()
    }

}
```

Now, in the above example, I'm just updating the `CAShapeLayer` of the seconds hand in my `CADisplayLink` handler. Like I said at the start, you can alternatively have a `draw` method that simply strokes the paths you need for single frame of animation and then call `setNeedsDisplay` in your display link handler. But if you do that, don't change the view hierarchy within `draw`, but rather do any configuration you need in `init` and `draw` should just `stroke` whatever the path should be at that moment.

Comment: Thanks mate! Will definitely look more into CADisplayLink